# How to Disable a value in drop down rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am having problem in  how to remove the value from drop down list after submitting the form.
I have route model which contains `:route_name`, `:no_of_stop`, and `:vehicle_id`  attributes.  For example, `vehicle_id`'s are 1, 2, 3. If you selected 1 while submitting the form, it won't display in other entry. i.e `vehicle_id`'s will be 2,3 likewise..

In View

```
 <%= simple_form_for(@route, html: {class: 'form-inline form-horizontal'}, :validate => true) do |f|%>
 <p><font color="red">Fields with * are required.</font></p>
    <%= f.input :route_name %>
    <%= f.input :no_of_stop, as: 'string' %>
    <div class="control-group string optional route_vehicle_id">
      <label class="string optional control-label" for="vehicle_id">Vehicle Code</label>
        <div class="controls">
         <%= f.select :vehicle_id, vehicle_list, {} , {class: 'input-mini add-margin' } %>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary") do %>
    <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Save
  <% end %>
</div>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are allocation vehicles. If you allocate the vehicle 1, in the next form presentation, you have only the vehicle 2 and 3 available, right?

If so, when you populate the `vehicle_list` variable, introduce a condition to not select those vehicles already allocated.